# Cannot access android.R.drawable.timepicker_input

Tags: android

Hello there i'm trying to write a layout similar to the timepicker widget layout.

So i decided to use the android framework layouts but i can't use them It seems that if i write android.R.drawable.timepicker_input or other timepicker related drawables i get them this Eclipse error:

> android.R.drawable.timepicker_up_btn cannot be resolved

So i tried to import all the pngs and xml  from the android source but eclipse says there is an error in the manifest regarding the icon.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resource is not available for development.

Solution:  get the file from the source code (http://source.android.com/)
copy it inside your project and use it

Comment: I had the same problem and downloaded the whole source (~10GB) to get some drawables. unfortunately i can't find them in there

Comment: Unfortunately now you cant browse the code online so its a pain to download the complete code.  Still you can look into google and you can get results like this one where the images are available :  http://code.google.com/p/intervalbeeper/source/browse/trunk/IntervalBeeper/res/?r=11#res%2Fdrawable-hdpi%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the internal android resources are available to use.  If android.R.drawable.timepicker_up_btn gives you that error then it is probably one of the resources that is internal.